# Easy way to protect a battery from charging

Tags: diodes

I am looking for an easy way to protect a battery from charging.
I have a one cell li/ion that should supply the electronic of a board with a connector usb c (one connector from the battery, one on the other PCB). The one cell battery 3V will be removed every time we want to charge the battery with a battery charger.
As you know usb C as the same connector on each ends, what I don't want is that we can connect a usb C 5V directly to the battery. 
If I put just a diode do you think it's gonna be enough to provide only one way for the current?
Thank you

Comment: You want to protect battery, but what about your device? If you have a device with Type-C connector, but powered at 3V, sooner or later someone will plug it into USB 5-V port, which will blow out your 3-V electronics. The whole idea of non-standard use of Type-C connector doesn't seem to be very well thought.

Comment: Have you considered just using a general Lithium Ion protection circuit?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: A diode will protect your battery from charging. But be aware that you might lose about 0.7V (depending on what diode you use) of the battery's voltage because of the diode's forward voltage. But this only happens if you connect your circuit on the same side as the diode's cathode is. If you connect the circuit on the anode side, it won't be supplied by the USB 5V, like your battery.

Also as stated in your comments, connecting a 3V circuit to a 5V USB doesn't seem to be that good of an idea.